# C# HTML GetElementById.setAttribute inputs in the wrong textbox

Tags: c#, html

I've been trying to make a login program for my games.
There is a website with

```
<input class="id" id="SiteId" maxlength="15" name="Id" style="width: 224px;ime-mode:inactive;" type="text" value="ID">
```

Like this in the Left of the login page and there is

```
<input class="id txt_b" id="Id" maxlength="15" name="Id" style="width: 224px;ime-mode:disabled;" type="text" value="ID">
```

this in the right page. I need to put my values in to the right place which id is "Id". But it keeps on putting values on the right side of the page. I coded like this.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Id").SetAttribute("value", idText.Text);
```

And also the password wouldn't put my values in it.

HTML

```
<input type="password" id="Password" class="pws txt_b bg_pw2" maxlength="15" value="" style="width: 224px; ime-mode: disabled;">
```

C# Code

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Password").SetAttribute("value", pwText.Text);
```

How can i fix this problem? I really want to finish it up. Thank you.

Comment: it must be `setAttribute()` not `SetAttribute()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop each element on web page. And based on class name select needed object. Here is example:

```
var inputs = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (inputs.GetAttribute("className") == "id txt_b")
    {
        inputs.SetAttribute("value", idText.Text);
    }
}
```

Just in case, check inputs.GetAttribute("className") for your case needs.